# When using ScrollViewer's ViewChanging event, e.IsInertial always returns false. [UWP]

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

According to Microsoft's documents, e.IsInertial should return true under conditions such as when the mouse wheel scrolls the ScrollViewer's contents. No matter what I do it always returns false. I need to know when the user's mouse wheel caused the ScrollViewer to scroll.

ScrollViewer has a ViewChanging event that allows access to the IsInertial property, btw.

Help, please. Thanks in advance. :]

Comment: I thought `IsInertial` is only true when user flicks with touch scrolling.

Comment: Could you provide some your xaml code that return false? In my test, the [IsInertial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewerviewchangingeventargs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs_IsInertial) property always return true with only some TextBlocks using a mouse wheel.